# Flex properties behave strangely when used in HTTPService

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I'm writing a Flex app using REST requests and trying to avoid HTTP caching as well as synchronize client/server time. To this end I've created a `timestamp` property as such:

```
// returns a timestamp corrected for server time            
private function get timestamp() : Number
{
    return new Date().getTime() + clientClockAdjustMsec;
}
```

(The `clientClockAdjustMsec` I've already set using special mojo)

I also attempt to include the timestamp in my query string like this:

```
<mx:HTTPService url="/Service?ts={timestamp}" ...
```

But what I see in the access logs is weird. It's something like this:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [06/Aug/2009:17:19:47 +0000] "GET /Service?ts=1249579062937 HTTP/1.1" 200 478
1.2.3.4 - - [06/Aug/2009:17:20:13 +0000] "GET /Service?ts=1249579062937 HTTP/1.1" 200 500
1.2.3.4 - - [06/Aug/2009:17:20:14 +0000] "GET /Service?ts=1249579062937 HTTP/1.1" 200 435
```

See how the timestamps are all the same? So strange. I would expect it to evaluate the property every time, as it does for Bindable variables.

(Actually, I just checked again and it does do the same thing for Bindable variables. But not with all clients. Do some versions of Flash have "issues"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is a read only getter? Binding isn't going to update {timestamp} in your HTTPService component as it has no property to bind to. timestamp is the output of a function (as Christopher mentions below) and is not a Bindable property. You need to either create a bindable property, or explicitly set the URL with a current timestamp, avoiding binding altogether.

Someplace in your code you are using myService.send(), you need to do something like:

```
[Bindable]
private var timestamp:Number;

private function whereSendHappens():void
{
    timestamp = new Date().getTime() + clientClockAdjustMsec;
    myService.send()
}

<mx:HTTPService url="/Service?ts={timestamp}" ...
```

if for some reason that didn't work:

```
private function whereSendHappens():void
{
    timestamp = new Date().getTime() + clientClockAdjustMsec;
    myService.url = "/Service?ts=" + timestamp;
    myService.send();
}
```

thus avoiding any binding issues...

Comment: Joel is correct. Because you're never telling your HTTPService that the value of `timestamp` has changed, it doesn't know to update the data bindings.

Comment: *TECHNICALLY* this isn't data binding as it relates to the output value of a function not a property.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your elaboration Christopher. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The other thing you can do is make the get function bindable to a specific event.

```
[Bindable("updateTimestamp")]
public function get timestamp() : Number { ... }

public function whereSendHappens():void
{
    dispatchEvent(new Event("updateTimestamp")); // will cause the binding to fire
    myService.send();
}
```